# Is it valid to ask multiple questions (on same topic) in a single post on Meta?

Tags: support

I think, in DA it's not a valid behavior to ask multiple questions in single post (Even on same topic). But is it valid here (on Meta)?

For example I've a multiple questions on Wiki Post. So is it valid to include all my questions in a single post?

Comment: Yes, always ask one question per question (often you'll see multiple question marks in a single question, but the question itself is on a single topic. That's fine). That way answers can be specific to what was asked. If you have other queries, ask new questions for them

Comment: @Clive - Oh ok! Its clear now. Thanks :)